# Please help debug the .js on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a few issues regarding .JS on my website. I've developed and built the website myself from scratch and I have knowledge with HTML and CSS but when it comes to .JS I'm clueless. I believe it may be something to do with conflicting .JS and Mootools. You can access my site here: http://demo.lukesezpcsolutions.co.uk/

The problems seem to only be on the home / front page and they are both

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The first being,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
```

And the second,

```
    jQuery(".coockie_banner button").on('click', function() {
```

If anyone can help me resolve this i would very much appreciate it and be forever in your debt... It has been racking my brain for weeks and I have watched untold videos to solve the issue myself but I'm clueless and have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Can't verify the problem.

Comment: Nothing on the page seems to have the `.hasTooltip` class.

Comment: `.tooltip()` Have you included plugin file reference?

Comment: I have resolved the issues by removing the facebook updates module as it wasn't showing any feed data so i searched for another module and realised that none of them are showing the feed display which leads me to believe it is actually facebook who have changed the way you call the feed from the app. In removing it, it fixed the script errors :) Thank you for your replies and suggestions though, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have place the js file like below.

```
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just change the order and try onetime. Hopefully it will resolve the problem.

```
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I change the order due to it being PHP and not HTML the scripts are called automatically not placed manually in the HTML file. 

I have resolved the issues by removing the facebook updates module as it wasn't showing any feed data so i searched for another module and realised that none of them are showing the feed display which leads me to believe it is actually facebook who have changed the way you call the feed from the app. 

In removing it, it fixed the script errors :)

Thank you for your reply and suggestion though, it's greatly appreciated.